# How to install android with eclipse.?

Tags: android

I want to install android sdk with eclipse.i am also using Ubuntu as operating system.
Please give supports and also good study material on android.

Regards

Comment: Google it dude.. you can find many links answering your question..

Comment: Research before asking. Ask questions if you run into a brick wall. Asking before researching can mean that you don't really have an incentive to learn whatever you're trying to learn.

Comment: ok i got it,next time i'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start with the Android development with Eclipse, You have to install **`ADT Plugin for Eclipse`**.

First, Have a look at this installation steps: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

You can found step-by-step installation guidance here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#Installing

In above link, you will be having below guidance to set-up your environment for the android development with Eclipse:

1. Step 1. Preparing Your Development Computer
2. Step 2. Downloading the SDK Starter Package
3. Step 3. Installing the ADT Plugin for Eclipse
4. Step 4. Adding Platforms and Other Components
5. Step 5. Exploring the SDK (Optional)

In step 3, you will find:

1. Preparing Your Development Computer
2. Downloading the ADT Plugin
3. Configuring the ADT Plugin
4. Troubleshooting ADT Installation

Answer (score 5):

Wow before trying to use eclipse, there is that awsome tool called Google you should learn first :D

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html