# How to install total android environment in UBUNTU?

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install android with eclipse.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836279/how-to-install-android-with-eclipse)

I used windows before and from windows i downloaded all the ubuntu packages for android like jdk 1.7, eclipse, sdk and adt in tar.gz format, I have extracted those,but i am totally new in linux and there is no exe file, so how can i install these to develope android on my ubuntu?

Comment: Run `apt-get install packagename` inside your terminal to install packages you downloaded.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What files have you downloaded? Have you extracted them? If you extracted them, what are you having trouble finding? Please add more details to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Its as simple as you did it for Windows. Download the Eclipse for Linux from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Then Install the ADT from Help->Install New Software from eclipse as you did this in Windows.

Hope this will help...

Comment: I have all the required files downloaded, jDK, SDK, Eclipse, ADT, but all of them are in tar.gz format, I am totally new in ubuntu, now please tell me what to do next

Comment: you need to extract tar.gz using this command....gunzip file.tar.gz
tar -xvf file.tar

Comment: @LuckyBoy, it's better not to `gunzip` first since this wastes disk space (and I/O bandwidth). Just use one command: `tar -zxvf filename.tar.gz`.

Comment: u place ur android folder inside home directory....and then give the path of sdk frm eclipse.....

Comment: have u done wid installation...??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build AOSP, [they recommend](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) you first set up Ubuntu 10.04.

If you just want to build user applications with the SDK and Eclipse, follow [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html).

If you're asking how to install the SDK, it's just like on Windows - extract the archive and run "tools/android". It just happens to not have the `.exe` extension you are used to.

There is also a short walkthrough [here](http://onthefencedevelopment.com/blog/installing-eclipse-and-android-sdk-ubuntu-10041010).

I recommend going through all the steps in [this walkthrough](http://linuxconfig.org/get-started-with-android-application-development-using-linux-and-android-sdk), complete with pictures and examples of the exact commands you may need to type to get things working. (if you're not familiar with the command line, now is the time to get started)